# Xcode 9 beta 403 forbidden

Tags: xcode, developer-program, beta

For an old C++ project compilation test I would need to try the first XCode 9 beta specifically: http://adcdownload.apple.com/WWDC_2017/Xcode_9_beta/Xcode_9_beta.xip

However the page returns error "403 Forbidden" for me. I don't know whether link is down (from old comments, these versions were working 3 years ago), or it's restricted to paid accounts.

Could anyone confirm what's the case?

Thanks.

Comment: Could anyone which happen to have this old beta upload it for sharing?

Comment: Just a comment. Any developer that shares, uploads Xcode or any beta software would possibly be in violation of both their NDA and the overall developer legal agreement. We are not here to be Apple police, but soliciting Apple beta software sharing is very much off topic here. Also, I am not a lawyer, but the license seems pretty clear about in no way sharing or uploading outside your team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paid up developers can not see any old betas for redownload. You typically need a support case and a very compelling reason to get anything beta from Apple once they update to a new beta. Save your downloads if you ever think you need them later.

That being said, all the release versions of 9 that are available:

- https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Assuming you don’t want the last version of 8, here is the oldest 9.0

- https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9/Xcode_9.xip

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware about where to download more public versions, but I'm looking for this beta. If you don't mind me asking, do you have a paid account so we can confirm old betas like this were removed? Note: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44389843/6855606) for reference.

Comment: I’ve updated my answer @Adrián also, your question is a very legitimate reason to Ask Apple for that download. I’ve had good luck working with developer support for what might seem an unusual request once they realize why you’re asking for a specific version.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to contact them then!